# How to serve word , excel , ppt and pdf files from node.js server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file, file-upload, autodesk-viewer

**I have successfully upload file from mongoDB to my node.js server**

Screen Short given below:

[click here to see Screen Short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wszop.png)

but I have no idea how to serve these files from node.js server to client side ..

**Very Thankfull to advance**

Comment: Please post your code directly to question, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

With this code, when you click a link to `/pdf` endpoint, the client will download a file with desired name.

```js
app.get('/pdf', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + desiredName)
  res.type(yourDataType)
  res.status(200).send(Buffer.from(yourBufferFromFile, 'binary'))
})
```